# Define a custom route with an extra id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My `Team` controller with a custom action named `list_questions` needs to receive an extra id, the `:exercise_id`. Here is how am I trying to do this:

```
resources :teams do
  member do
    post :enroll
    post :unenroll
    get 'exercises/:exercise_id/list_questions'
  end
end
```

However, I receive the following error: `ArgumentError: Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes.`

What is the better way to accomplish that?

Comment: You must understan the difference between `member` and `collection`. A `member` route will require an `ID`, because it acts on a member. A `collection` route doesn't because it acts on a collection of objects

Comment: Rigth. My interpretation was: I still need my `team_id`, so I put my desired route inside a `member` block from my `team` resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because the action for that route is not defined.

try something like this

```
resources :teams do
  member do
    post :enroll
    post :unenroll

    get 'list_questions(/exercises/:exercise_id)',
      to: "teams#list_questions",
      as: :list_questions
  end
end
```

and you can build the url this way:

```
list_questions_teams_path(@team, @exercise)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would just follow your ressourceful routes approach like:

```
resources :teams do
  member do
    post :enroll
    post :unenroll
    resources :exercises do
       member do
         resources :list_questions  
       end
    end 
  end
end
```

will generate:

```
        enroll_team POST     /teams/:id/enroll(.:format)                                                    teams#enroll
      unenroll_team POST     /teams/:id/unenroll(.:format)                                                  teams#unenroll
     list_questions GET      /teams/:id/exercises/:id/list_questions(.:format)                              list_questions#index
                    POST     /teams/:id/exercises/:id/list_questions(.:format)                              list_questions#create
  new_list_question GET      /teams/:id/exercises/:id/list_questions/new(.:format)                          list_questions#new
 edit_list_question GET      /teams/:id/exercises/:id/list_questions/:id/edit(.:format)                     list_questions#edit
      list_question GET      /teams/:id/exercises/:id/list_questions/:id(.:format)                          list_questions#show
                    PATCH    /teams/:id/exercises/:id/list_questions/:id(.:format)                          list_questions#update
                    PUT      /teams/:id/exercises/:id/list_questions/:id(.:format)                          list_questions#update
                    DELETE   /teams/:id/exercises/:id/list_questions/:id(.:format)                          list_questions#destroy
          exercises GET      /teams/:id/exercises(.:format)                                                 exercises#index
                    POST     /teams/:id/exercises(.:format)                                                 exercises#create
       new_exercise GET      /teams/:id/exercises/new(.:format)                                             exercises#new
      edit_exercise GET      /teams/:id/exercises/:id/edit(.:format)                                        exercises#edit
           exercise GET      /teams/:id/exercises/:id(.:format)                                             exercises#show
                    PATCH    /teams/:id/exercises/:id(.:format)                                             exercises#update
                    PUT      /teams/:id/exercises/:id(.:format)                                             exercises#update
                    DELETE   /teams/:id/exercises/:id(.:format)                                             exercises#destroy
              teams GET      /teams(.:format)                                                               teams#index
                    POST     /teams(.:format)                                                               teams#create
           new_team GET      /teams/new(.:format)                                                           teams#new
          edit_team GET      /teams/:id/edit(.:format)                                                      teams#edit
               team GET      /teams/:id(.:format)                                                           teams#show
                    PATCH    /teams/:id(.:format)                                                           teams#update
                    PUT      /teams/:id(.:format)                                                           teams#update
                    DELETE   /teams/:id(.:format)                                                           teams#destroy
```

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default